# /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50: error adding symbols：DSO missing from command line

Tags: linker-errors, automake, icu

When I'm compiling my project, I've encountered the following compile error: undefined reference to symbol 'uregex_open_50'
`/usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50: error adding symbols：DSO  missing from command line`.

I add `-licui18n -licuuc -licudata` link flags in Makefile.am.

use`make -j32 -C src`.

Then I use `readeld -s /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50 | grep uregex_open_50`,and find it.

Then I found that in urename.h file there is macro about function name substitution.
#define uregex_open U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(uregex_open) U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(x) x ## _50. So the function name in the final project is replaced with a name with a _50 suffix.I want to know how to solve this problem.